# Redux - Ngrx action dispatch asynchronous treatment

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have a time slider that trigger action to filter data every change

```
this.selectedDate$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(elm => {
      this.selectedTime = elm.timeSelect;
      this.store.dispatch(new GetSchedulesByTime(elm.timeSelect.toString()));
      return this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulings));
    })
  )
  .subscribe((schedules: ISchedule[]) => {
...});
```

`GetSchedulesByTime` update a store with new data;

`selectSchedulings` is a selector of this new data

What happens is when `selectedDate` the action is dispatched , selector still points to last state, so my treatment is distorted.

Here's my action code

```
case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByTime: {
  let time = action.payload;
  return { ...state, actualTrips: [...(state.schedulings[time] || [])] };
}
```

And selector

```
export const selectSchedulings = createSelector(
  schedulings,
  (state: ISchedulesState) => state.actualTrips
);
```

How to be sure that selector is pointing to the new state before return it  ?

Comment: Does `this.store.dispatch(new GetSchedulesByTime(elm.timeSelect.toString()));` action calls backend? If so then how do you know that the backend call is complete? I guess you should have a state which shows that the call is complete. You need to watch for that state and then use the selector.

Comment: It does not call backend it only update state by filtering data that is in the store

Comment: Can you try after applying `delay` operator like this: `return this.store.pipe(delay(1), select(selectSchedulings));`

Comment: I think you should use an effect for this. Unfortunately I don't have the time to code up an example for you. But your Effect would be responsible for calling your API and dispatching an action to change state

Comment: No api is called , it takes a state `appState: { alldata}`and filter then save data in `appSate : { filteredData }`

Comment: As dispatch is async even if I use effect inside it I think it will pass to the return line anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little understanding on how the dispatch and select actually work.

**Dispatch**
When you dispatch an action, it calls for an effect if it exists. The output of effect or the action payload is directly transferred to the reducer that updates the state.

**select**
The selectors help you select a particular part of your state. `this.store.select` basically returns you an observable that you can subscribe to. This subscription means that anytime there is a change in state, your subscription callback will be called.

Hence, what you essentially need to do is to take out the selector and subscribe to it as shown below:

```
this.scheduling$ = this.store.select(scheduleSelectors.selectSchedulings);
this.scheduling$.subscribe((data)->{
//do something with the data
//This is called everything state changes
})
```

Thus, you do not need to pipe the selector each time. Just subscribing to it once is sufficient. On every dispatch of action, your state should change and that will in turn call the above subscription. To validate this fact, you can debug your code and check for yourself.